# Play song with disabling any layer of music

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application I want to play 1 song from music library. Now while playing song, i want to disable any layer of music for e.x guitar or drum or flute etc. And rest should play as it is without that specific disabled layer. is this possible with iOS to disable music layers?

Can any one guide me please or any link ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, there are no layers of music, its simply a digital file. for this to be done clearly you would need individual tracks for each instrument, or like dj's they have to buy or download special recordings that have vocal and separate instrumental versions of a song and even the instrumentals have all the instruments blended together the only people who have to access to separating instruments are the actual people who created the music. the only possible way is if you look into frequency filter effect, it's how apps remove vocals. The trick is its not really removing vocals, vocals are just kind of high so its turning down the high parts of the song.